# Editar dados específicos do XML com LOOP usando formulário em arquivo PHP

Tags: php, xml, loop

Estou com alguns problemas ao tentar editar dados específicos (com LOOP) do XML com formulário em uma página PHP.

Arquivo PHP: input.php (sem loop)

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $carregador_xml=simplexml_load_file('minha_lista.xml');
        $carregador_xml->lista->título=$_POST['título'];
        $função=fopen("minha_lista.xml","wb");
        fwrite($função,$carregador_xml->asXML());
        fclose($função);
    }
    $carregador_xml=simplexml_load_file('minha_lista.xml');
    $título=$carregador_xml->lista->título;
?>
<form id="yourFormId" method="post">
    <input name="título" value="<?php echo $título ?>">
    <input class="submitBtn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar Registro!">
</form>
```

Arquivo PHP: input.php (com loop)

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<?php
    $carregador_xml = simplexml_load_file("minha_lista.xml");
    foreach($carregador_xml->children() as $lista){
?>
<form method="post">
    <input name="título" value="<?php echo $título ?>">
    <input class="submitBtn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar Registro!">
</form>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $carregador_xml=simplexml_load_file('minha_lista.xml');
        $carregador_xml->lista->título=$_POST['título'];
        $handle=fopen("minha_lista.xml","wb");
        fwrite($handle,$carregador_xml->asXML());
        fclose($handle);
    }
    $título = $lista->título;
}
?>
```

Como eu faço para gerar um loop de formulários de edição para cada dado específico do XML que esteja dentro das tags título e /título ? (No caso da minha input.php sem loop, eu só consigo exibir a primeira lista, como eu posso fazer para gerar outras além dela?

Arquivo XML: minha_lista.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<banco-de-dados>
    <lista>
        <título>Título 1</título>
    </lista>
    <lista>
        <título>Título 2</título>
    </lista>
</banco-de-dados>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue um Código que deve funcionar para o que você quer.

> *NOTA*: Não use caracteres especiais em código, seja PHP ou XML.
>   Caracteres especiais somente para texto a ser lido, fora isso, evite.

Mude seu XML para este aqui, onde removi o caractere especial do nome da tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<banco-de-dados>
    <lista>
        <titulo>Título 1</titulo>
    </lista>
    <lista>
        <titulo>Título 2</titulo>
    </lista>
    <lista>
        <titulo>Título 3</titulo>
    </lista>
    <lista>
        <titulo>Título N</titulo>
    </lista>
</banco-de-dados>
```

Para a sua lista de títulos, não creio que seja necessário um form para cada item da lista (jamais usaria  assim). 
Um só já é suficiente, porém ele irá alterar todos sempre com o código apresentado.

```
<form method="post">
<?php
    $carregador_xml = simplexml_load_file("minha_lista.xml");
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($carregador_xml->children() as $lista) { ?>        
    <input name="titulo[<?php echo $i++; ?>]" value="<?php echo $lista->titulo; ?>"> <br />    
<?php } ?>

    <input class="submitBtn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Salvar Registros!">
</form>
```

Já o código que escreve de volta as alterações pode ser esse aqui

```
if (isset($_POST['titulo'])) {
    $titulos = (array) $_POST['titulo'];
    $carregador_xml = simplexml_load_file('minha_lista.xml');
    $funcao = fopen("minha_lista.xml", "wb");
    foreach ($titulos as $num => $titulo) {
        $i = 1;
        foreach ($carregador_xml->children() as $lista) {
            if ($i++ == $num ) {
                $lista->titulo = $titulo ; 
                break 1;
            }
        }       

    }
    fwrite($funcao, $carregador_xml->asXML());
    fclose($funcao);        

}
```

> *NOTA 2*: Se os Títulos vão conter caracteres especiais além dos acentos, pode ser necessário usar sessão CDATA, porém o simplexml não dá suporte a criar estas sessões, sendo necessário o uso de DOM. Já utilizei [esta solução aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6260295/5429350) que considero muito elegante.

Comment: Então, eu inseri tudo aí, mas quando eu coloco o valor na segunda input e clico para enviar, ele automaticamente envia o valor da segunda input para a primeira... tem algum método para fazer com que eu gere um formulário específico para cada tag lista sem a necessidade de inserir ids(nums) em cada tag lista? algo do tipo foreach ou while para gerar um loop de formularios igual a quantidade de tags lista dentro da xml.

Comment: Acredito que agora está como você deseja. Caso decida usar mesmo um formulário para cada, apenas coloque a tag form dentro do loop, o codigo continuará válido.

Comment: ótimo, funcionou perfeitamente! sou grato pela ajuda.